How to split database entities or access responsibilities of services to these entities
I have two services, auth-sync and twitter-indexer.
We use Privy for auth (incl. SSO with 3rd parties). We sync our userbase from Privy to our own DB for certain analytics purposes. And the auth-sync service takes care of that syncing job. It stores user records in a table called privy_users. All our users have their twitter usernames alongside their profiles in Privy, so each record in the privy_users table will have the twitter_handle column populated.
The twitter-indexer service is scraping data and metrics about out users from Twitter, like account age, followers count, metadata about certain posts, etc.
In order to know for which twitter users to scrape data, the twitter-indexer needs to know the twitter handles of our users. These come from the privy_users table. And when it scrapes data (eg. followers count) it needs to store it somewhere.
I do not want to store the scraped metrics and data in the privy_users table, because

I want to keep that table lean
it's not good practice to allow more than 1 service to write to the same table

Therefore, I've taken on the approach to "sync" users from the privy_users table to another table (twitter_users), and then based on the records (user handles) from that table, the twitter-indexer will scrape Twitter.
What I don't like in this architecture is that I have to sync data from one of my tables to another.
Therefore, I was wondering, if there is a better/smarter approach to this.

I'm confused about why you think you are syncing data from privy_users to twitter_users. What you describe doesn't sound like synchronizing data at all.

@GregBurghardt, syncing or copying over - just a matter of wording.

Syncing and copying are two different things. Syncing implies the information should be synchronized. Copying just moving it from one location to another without regard to keeping them in sync (although that might also be included).


What I don't like in this architecture is that I have to sync data from one of my tables to another.

Get used to it, problem solved. When dealing with concurrent processes or services which have their own data, but some common key, eventual consistency is nothing special. That is the trade-off for decoupling the two services.

Haha, yeah, I know it's a tradeoff for decoupling the services, but was wondering if anyone has a better architecture in mind. So, I guess you don't have that for me?

@Milkncookiez: Doc Brown is saying that the services are decoupled, which is the root cause of your problem. Unless you can combine them into one service and solve the concurrency issues, you have this problem. It's also a common problem in microservices and service oriented architecture.
